# How to call a function from one file inside another function from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

```
Folder1
  -file1.py
    -class A 
       -func1()
       -func2()

Folder2
 -file2.py
  -class B
     -func3()
        how to call func1() of class A here?
```

Assuming Folder1 and Folder2 are part of project structure folder

If i am trying like below

```
from Folder1.file1 import A


Folder2
  -file2.py
    -class B
       -func3()
          A.func1()
```

I am getting ModuleNotFound error while importing 
from Folder1.file1 import A

Comment: Read this? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want this structure

```
app/
  __init__.py 
  Folder1/
    __init__.py
    file1.py
  Folder2/
    __init__.py
    file2.py
```

With this code in any file within app folder

```
from app.Folder1.file1 import A 
A.func1()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python looks for modules in `sys.path`**.

To use `file1` as a module, you should add its path to `sys.path`.

```py
# add module path to sys.path
import os.path as osp
import sys
file_dir = osp.dirname(osp.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(osp.join(file_dir, '..')) 

# then you can import the module
from folder1.file1 import A
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure to include `__init__.py` (empty file is fine) under each folder

Answer (score 0):

add `__init__.py` in both folder then import that file using `from foldername.filename import classname` and you can make a call